# Вопрос про IF, AND и OR. Без привязки к языку

Tags: if, логика

Вообще у меня 2 вопроса, но они очень схожи меж собой. 
Допустим что у нас есть некоторый, синтаксически правильно написанный код на каком-то языке. В нем присутствует условный оператор `if` с 2 операндами *(для простоты я скажу, что первый операнд это ЛОЖЬ, а второй — ИСТИНА)*.

Эти два операнда стоят в одном условии и соединяются логическим **`И`**. 
По таблице истинности **`И`** известно что если хотя-бы один операнд `ЛОЖЬ`, то и при проверке на истинность, тоже `ЛОЖЬ`.

И вот вопрос: если при выполнении кода *первый* операнд будет `ЛОЖЬ`, а следом логическое **`И`**, то будет ли проверяться второй операнд?

И второй вопрос, *(обратный первому)*: если *первый* операнд `ИСТИНА`, а следом логическое **`ИЛИ`**, то будет ли проверяться второй операнд?

Comment: и там и там не будет проверяться следующий операнд, т.к. по первому всё стало ясно

Comment: Никогда не думал что такое возможно. Увидел как друг написал: `if (oper1) {if (oper2) {}, вместо if (oper1 && oper2) {}`, сказав мол так быстрее компелится, вот и стало интересно. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Так пусть докажет что быстрее ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   а ещё, что эта скорость оправдана... что она не 0.00001 мс а именно существенная и критичная для приложения...... ещё бы хотелось взглянуть как он будет писать условия где будет, положим 5 И (где должно быть `op1 && op2 && op3 && op4 && op5 ` ...видимо это будет лестница в ад :D)

Comment: Понятия не имею почему должно компилироваться быстрее, но читаемость становится ужасной

Comment: Зависит от реализации конкретного оператора в конкретном языке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В большинстве языков программирования есть договорённость, что для **логических операторов** используется "оптимизированный" вариант проверки: если при проверке одного из условий уже точно известно, какой будет результат, то остальные проверки не исполняются. Пример на питоне:

```py
if print('первое') and print('второе'):
    print('выполнилось')

if print('первое') is None or print('второе'):
    print('выполнилось')
```

Вывод:

```
первое
первое
выполнилось
```

- после получения `False` интерпретатор понял, что `and` уже никак "не взлетит" и посчитал всё выражение равным `False`, вторая проверка не стала выполняться
- после получения `True` выражение с `or` стало истинным в любом случае и `if` сработал

Но следует помнить, что такое поведение прописано только для, повторюсь, **логических операторов**. А вот для **битовых операторов** уже не так, для них выполняется всё выражение, даже если результат уже должен быть понятен, такая договорённость.

```
if int(print('первое') is not None) & int(print('второе') is None):
    print('выполнилось')

if int(print('первое') is None) | int(print('второе') is not None):
    print('выполнилось')
```

Вывод:

```
первое
второе
первое
второе
выполнилось
```

В данном случае то, что мы считаем значения `0 & x` и `1 | x`, которые в итоге будучи в конце приведёнными к `bool` и проверенными в `if` уже заранее понятно к какому результату приведут, не мешает компилятору вычислять правые части этих выражений. Такова договорённость.

P.S. Не могу однозначно сказать, как будет вести себя в подобных ситуациях, например, `C++` с теми или иными флагами компиляции, возможно там поведение будет отличаться. Но общепринятая конвенция для языков программирования вот такая.

Answer (score 5):

За другие языки не знаю, но в джаве для этого есть отдельные операторы:

| выражение | поведение |
| --- | --- |
| `a || b` | `а` или `b` истинно, `b` оценивается условно |
| `a | b` | `а` или `b` истинно, `b` оценивается в любом случае |

Answer (score -1):

2 fixed

```js
let x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
```

```html
<p onclick='if(++x[0] > x[1] || ++x[1] > x[0]){alert("x0=" + x[0] + "; x1=" + x[1])}'>1 в принципе ожидаемо</p>
<p onclick='if(++x[2] > x[3] && ++x[3] == x[2]){alert("x2=" + x[2] + "; x3=" + x[3])}'>2 тож норм</p>
<p onclick='if(++x[4] > x[5] xor --x[5] < x[4]){alert("x4=" + x[4] + "; x5=" + x[5])}'>!3</p>
```

Comment: Если в условии стоит какое-то вычисляемое выражение - это некорректное условие  и неправильно так писать в принципе. Грубо говоря там должны быть однозначно опредёлённые значения в переменных. Так что пример некорректен только потому, что там писать никогда нельзя.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и тем не менее, для "собственноручно выяснить кто первее", вполне сгодится

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и кстати, с чего это вдруг вычисляемое условие некорректное? есть такая штука как циклы, for в частности, один из основных способов перебора им массивов как раз с запихиванием кремента в условие:
`for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   console.log(i);
}`
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Это не условие, это выражение, которое будет выполняться в конце цикла. Никакого отношения к условию оно не имеет.  Молодец, что нашёл ссылку, почитай как раз её сам, изучи основы))